# What would be the easiest way to print the top 10 players from my database to a page?

Tags: mysql, database, sails.js

I am using mysql and sails.js. When I want to query the top 10 people of the game I use:

`Select name, totalwins/totalgames from user order by totalwins desc limit 10;`

This displays something like this in my terminal (shortened to 3 for example):

```
+-----------------------+----------------------+
| name                  | totalwins/totalgames |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
| name 1                |               1.7917 |
| name 2                |               1.5417 |
| name 3                |               0.3333 |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

If I also wanted to print this to my page to essentially make a scoreboard that updates on refresh, how could I go about doing this? Is there a universal way to do this with mysql?

Comment: Is your table column really named "totalwins/totalgames"?

Comment: No, I'm dividing the columns `totalwins` by `totaltgames` to basically simulate a batting average.

Comment: Adam means you should add `totalwins/totalgames AS WinLoseRatio` (or something different)

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Sails has answers for all the pieces. It uses Models and waterline to query for the data (in a controller), and one way to put that on a webpage is to use a sails view. Do you need help with all of these steps, or just one part?

Comment: @arbuthnott I'm primarily a front end dev, so node, sails and MVC in general is brand new to me. I would say I could figure out the view part, but the model and controller is a little weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I can assume you have a sails model and controller: `User` and `UserController`. (If not, the sails docs or in-project comments should make these easy to create). Then you can set up a page to be served from a method in your UserController by adding this to the routes file (`/config/routes.js`):

```
'GET /mypage': 'UserController.displayPage',
```

Then in you UserController (`/api/controllers/UserController.js`):

```
module.exports = {
    displayPage: function(req, res) {
        User.find({}).sort('totalWins DESC').limit(10).exec(function(err, users) {
            if (err) { /* handle errors */ }
            // users has the objects you want in the order you specified
            // send them to a view using res.view
            return res.view('myview', {users: users});
        });
    },
    // ...
}
```

This will send the data to a view at `/views/myview.ejs`. It's a templatable (basically) html page, but in it you can access your `users` object and use standard templating notation. For ex:

```
<% for (var idx = 0; idx < users.length; idx++) { %>
<tr>
    <td><%= users[idx].name %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

etc.

It's a lot of steps, but none are insurmountable!